# ceph rook deployment issue found at mount pvc

Tags: kubernetes, ceph

I am warren . try to setup ceph by rook in my k8s environment . i followed the offical document
https://rook.io/docs/rook/v1.4/ceph-quickstart.html.  almaost everythings looks well during the ceph setup.  I also verified it by

ceph status
cluster:
id:     356efdf1-a1a7-4365-9ee6-b65ecf8481f9
health: HEALTH_OK

But failed at examples https://rook.io/docs/rook/v1.4/ceph-block.html, try to use block storage in the k8s environment. my k8s env is v1.18.2.

after deploy mysql and workpress. found error at pod . like below. I also checked the pv and pvc. all of them created success and bounded. so I thinks something error about mount compatibility.  please help.

```
-----------------------------------------------------
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                  From                     Message
  ----     ------                  ----                 ----                     -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling        <unknown>            default-scheduler        running "VolumeBinding" filter plugin for pod "wordpress-mysql-764fc64f97-qwtjd": pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims
  Warning  FailedScheduling        <unknown>            default-scheduler        running "VolumeBinding" filter plugin for pod "wordpress-mysql-764fc64f97-qwtjd": pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims
  Normal   Scheduled               <unknown>            default-scheduler        Successfully assigned default/wordpress-mysql-764fc64f97-qwtjd to master1
  Normal   SuccessfulAttachVolume  7m14s                attachdetach-controller  AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "pvc-dc8567bb-c2e3-44a4-a56a-c74616059db4"
  Warning  FailedMount             5m11s                kubelet, master1         Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[mysql-persistent-storage], unattached volumes=[default-token-czg9j mysql-persistent-storage]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount             40s (x2 over 2m54s)  kubelet, master1         Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[mysql-persistent-storage], unattached volumes=[mysql-persistent-storage default-token-czg9j]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount             6s (x4 over 6m6s)    kubelet, master1         MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "pvc-dc8567bb-c2e3-44a4-a56a-c74616059db4" : rpc error: code = Internal desc = rbd: map failed with error an error (exit status 110) occurred while running rbd args: [--id csi-rbd-node -m 10.109.63.94:6789,10.96.135.241:6789,10.110.131.193:6789 --keyfile=***stripped*** map replicapool/csi-vol-5ccc546b-0914-11eb-9135-62dece6c0d98 --device-type krbd], rbd error output: rbd: sysfs write failed
-------------------------------------------------
```